# Dynamic Screen Flow Navigation with Jetpack-Compose reusing existing Screens (KMM)

Tags: dynamic, navigation, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform

I need to implement navigation within a flow (e.g. authentication) which should be able to reuse existing screens and pass data from one screen to the next. Generally a flow can contain multiple screens each needing parameters from the previous screens. Additionally, based on the initial start destination the reused screen has different functionality and the final navigation differs as well. See below for detailed flows:

Screens: Login, Register, ConfirmOtp, Home, Welcome, Onboarding

Flow1: Home > Login > ConfirmOtp (invoke HomeCallback) > Home

Flow2: Home > Register > ConfirmOtp (invoke HomeCallback) > Welcome

Flow3: Onboarding > Register > ConfirmOtp (invoke OnboardingCallback) > Welcome

I got a NavHost with different navigation graphs and am now researching how to best structure the code to support these requirements.

I found several different approaches how to pass data to a screen via navigation such as:

1. adding arguments to the route:

   - "Login/{flowStart}/{finalDestination}"
   - "Register/{flowStart}/{finalDestination}"
   - "ConfirmOtp/{flowStart}/{finalDestination}/{mobile}" (switch on flowStart to invoke the corresponding callback?)
2. using an "authentication flow" view model containing all necessary arguments that is initialized when the flow starts and passed to all screens:

   - finalNavigationRoute: string
   - confirmCallback: action
   - formData: data (contains mobile for ConfirmOtp)

I found couple other approaches which I didn't investigate yet but those two looked most promising. I'm not sure which is the most suitable approach to still keep everything manageable and testable. Does anyone have experience with dynamic flow navigation?